# Path working on PC but not Mac

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a problem with my VBA code on my mac computer. It works fine on Windows. I know it has something to do with specifying directory but I'm not sure on the right syntax.
The workbook is in a folder and then I want to specify another folder (Datatextfiles) which is in the same folder as the work book.

```
'Change Path
Dim strPath As String
Dim MyDir As String
MyDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path
strPath = MyDir & "/Datatextfiles/"

Dim strExtension As String

 'Stop Screen Flickering
Application.ScreenUpdating = Falsew

 'Change extension
strExtension = Dir(strPath & "*.txt")

clearData

Do While strExtension <> ""
```

Comment: It's also my understanding that Mac doesn't recognize file extensions. I am not able to test this, but I know that including file extension arguments will raise an error in some cases, like, `Application.GetOpenFileName()` or `.GetSaveAsFileName`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

NOne of y'all are right.  The proper designation for a folder separator on mac is a colon ':'  Such as

```
ChDir "KathyStringHD:Library:WebServer:Documents:DispatchReports:InTime:"
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are having a problem on the Mac because you aren't using a mac path separator for your path.

Try the following line of code:

```
strPath = MyDir & Application.PathSeparator & Datatextfiles & Application.PathSeparator
```