# Excel VBA addPicture by path to image

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I've written an VBA Macro on windows. This Macro adds pictures into my excel sheet based on the value of a cell e.g. 'image.png'. These images are located in the same directory as my Excel workbook. VBA will get the path to the workbook and use it to find the image specified in the cell. This works on windows, however it does not work on mac. The macro returns an error (1004) saying it can't find the specified file.

```
Sub InsertImage()
    Dim useless As Double
    Dim clTop As Double
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("C3:C200").Cells
       If c.Value = "" Then
           useless = 1
       Else
           Set cl = Range(c, c.Offset(0, 1))
           clTop = cl.Top
           ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture _
           Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & c.Value, _
           True, True, 500, clTop, 140, 140
       End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

Did some more testing: When I first manually add all the pictures that I want to add, then immediatly delete them all, then run exactly the same Macro, all the pictures are imported perfectly fine. Could this be a bug in Excel for Mac?

Comment: Did you see e.g. [this post?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631503/path-working-on-pc-but-not-mac)

Answer (score 1):

Leaving an answer here in case anyone still finds this page when banging their heads against a wall trying to insert multiple pictures into Excel for Mac, using VBA (like me). I found the GrantAccessToMultipleFiles help on this site here finally fixed it for me:
https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/systemsbiology/staff/dyer/software/excelvbafileopen/

Answer (score 0):

Macs don't use the same path separators as Windows (or even as each other). Change the code to this:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture _
           Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & c.Value, _
           msoFalse, msoTrue, 500, clTop, 140, 140
```

Comment: Tried this, now it adds empty rectangles with a red cross to my sheet saying: 'The linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been moved, renamed or deleted. Verify that the link points to the correct file and location.'

Comment: Can you manually insert the pictures on the Mac? If so, try recording a macro while you do it and see what you get for the parameters.

Comment: I tried adding one of them manually, which worked. Then when I ran the macro again, it works for none of the pictures except the one that was added manually before..

Comment: Did some more testing: When I first manually add all the pictures that I want to add, then immediatly delete them all, then run exactly the same Macro, all the pictures are imported perfectly fine. Could this be a bug in Excel for Mac?

Comment: It sounds very much like it. Is it 2016 or 2011?

Comment: Probably a bug then. ;) Were the pictures created on the Mac?

Comment: I see, yes they where. Thanks for your help btw :)

Comment: Do you need them to be linked?

Comment: I need them to be included in the .xlsx file, so I can mail a single file to someone else including the images.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125186/discussion-between-titsjmen-and-rory).