# macOS Sandbox preventing Excel VBA from accessing images on NAS

Tags: excel, vba, image, macos, appstore-sandbox

I have a spreadsheet on a NAS that is shared between Windows and Mac devices. The spreadsheet is a database of copyright permissions along with images, also held on the NAS. 
I use VBA to populate and name the images when an entry is created or amended. The code works fine on the Windows PC; but does not work when I run it on Mac OS, even with locally stored images. At first I played with permissions on the NAS - right up to connecting to it as Admin from the Mac. Also, If I accessed anything in Finder, all of the images were accessible and displayed.

After searching I suspected that the problem was related to Mac OS sandbox. This was evidenced by Mac OS asking for permission to access specific images when I open the spreadsheet, followed by errors when the code tries to access images. As a confirmation test I moved the entire folder structure into the Mac OS Office library environment to avoid any sandbox restrictions, as suggested in other posts, and then everything started to work perfectly.

Obviously storing everything locally doesn't make much sense in a shared environment! Thus, my questions are about overcoming access problems related to the sandbox in Mac OS.

Is there any way I can access the images and sheet on the NAS without these errors? 
Is there a VBA code solution?

Thanks for your help.

**ENVIRONMENT**

I am using EXCEL 2016 on both machines with the latest Office updates for
Windows 10 on the PC and Mac OS 10. The NAS is a Buffalo link station.

For info the error occurs on the 'set myPict' statement, - when it occurs. The error message is, for example, 'An error occurred while importing this file. /Volumes/Colour_Designer/Colour_Designer_image_database/5.jpg.'

The piece of code that does the work looks like this:-

```
If InStr(1, Application.OperatingSystem, "Mac", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
PictureLoc = "/Volumes/Colour_Designer/Colour_Designer_image_database/" & Target.Value & ".jpg"
Else
PictureLoc = "\\LS220D620\Colour_Designer\Colour_Designer_image_database\Photo Album 2020-04-23.album\" & Target.Value & ".jpg"
End If
 With Target.Offset(0, 5)
      Set myPict = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=PictureLoc, _
      LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
      SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
      Left:=myleft + 4, _
      Top:=mytop + 4, _
      Width:=-1, _
      Height:=-1)

      myPict.Height = .RowHeight
      myPict.Top = .Top
      myPict.Left = .Left
      myPict.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
      myPict.Name = "1"
      myPict.Name = Target.Value
End With
```

Note - The path is slightly different on the PC - it uses an .album extension on the folder name, which may also cause a problem on Mac OS; but 'one step at a time'.

Comment: It would be helpful if you include the exact error messages, and on what lines of the code they occur.

Comment: The error occurs on 'set myPict ' statement, (when it occurs).

Comment: Error message is - e.g. 

'An error occurred while importing this file. /Volumes/Colour_Designer/Colour_Designer_image_database/5.jpg'

Comment: You should include that in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA addPicture by path to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39895106/excel-vba-addpicture-by-path-to-image)

Comment: No - although I have seen it and found it useful. My question is not about the code. I am confident that it functions. The question is about security permissions on the MAC, especially the effect of the sandbox -see https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac034.htm