# Opening file on Mac generates Run-time error '53': File not found

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have Excel files generated using openxlsx library in R.

Since they contain formulas, each needs to be opened and saved before I can parse them to read data.

I created a macro to open, save, and close the Excel files.

```
Sub Macro1()
Path = "/Users/ytk/Desktop/2016-11-30/"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
Do While Filename <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename
    Workbooks(Filename).Close SaveChanges:=True
Loop
End Sub
```

I get:

> Run-time error '53':
>   File not found

That is the correct filepath. I'm running this on a Mac, Excel 2016.

Edit: I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631503/path-working-on-pc-but-not-mac), and changed the path separator to `:` instead of `/`:

```
Path = "Users:ytk:Desktop:2016-11-30:"
```

and I get the same error.

Comment: You're missing the drive at the beginning of the Path `Path = "C:/Use..`

Comment: @Sgdva since I'm running on a mac, it doesn't have drives like `C:` and `D:`. I found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631503/path-working-on-pc-but-not-mac, which might be the problem.